# How to get the gloss given sense key using Nltk WordNet?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I got a set of sense key such as "long%3:00:02::" from SemCor+OMSTI. How can I get the glosses? Is there a map file? Or using Nltk WordNet?

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

```
import re
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

sense_key_regex = r"(.*)\%(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)"
synset_types = {1:'n', 2:'v', 3:'a', 4:'r', 5:'s'}

def synset_from_sense_key(sense_key):
    lemma, ss_type, lex_num, lex_id, head_word, head_id = re.match(sense_key_regex, sense_key).groups()
    ss_idx = '.'.join([lemma, synset_types[int(ss_type)], lex_id])
    return wn.synset(ss_idx)

x = "long%3:00:02::"

synset_from_sense_key(x)
```

## In Long

There's this really obtuse function in NLTK. However, that doesn't read from the sense key but from `data_file_map` (e.g. "data.adj", "data.noun", etc.): https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1355

Since we already have a mere-mortal understandable API in NTLK, with some guides from https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/senseidx.5WN.html ,

```
A sense_key is represented as:

     lemma % lex_sense

where lex_sense is encoded as:

    ss_type:lex_filenum:lex_id:head_word:head_id


(yada, yada...)

The synset type is encoded as follows:
1    NOUN 
2    VERB 
3    ADJECTIVE 
4    ADVERB 
5    ADJECTIVE SATELLITE
```

we can do this using a regex https://regex101.com/r/9KlVK7/1/:

```
>>> import re
>>> sense_key_regex = r"(.*)\%(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)"

>>> x = "long%3:00:02::" 

>>> re.match(sense_key_regex, x)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10061ad78>

>>> re.match(sense_key_regex, x).groups()
('long', '3', '00', '02', '', '')

>>> lemma, ss_type, lex_num, lex_id, head_word, head_id = re.match(sense_key_regex, x).groups()


>>> synset_types = {1:'n', 2:'v', 3:'a', 4:'r', 5:'s'}


>>> '.'.join([lemma, synset_types[int(ss_type)], lex_id])
'long.a.02'
```

And voila you get the NLTK `Synset()` object from the sense key =)

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synset(idx)
Synset('long.a.02')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm not just using the word "long". What about others? Is there a mapping rule for all words?

Comment: Use the same function for other sense key

Comment: I tried,but the function is not correct for all sense keys. I have got a better method to solve this. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Now that's interesting. If the sense key is not correctly mapped as per the documentation, then `nltk` and the `wordnet` interface has some lossy issue. Could you give a couple example where the function gives the wrong mapping? That'll help us tremendously in correcting the lossy mappings!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just tried one word "love" which is not correct. So I think there must be more mistakes. You can test this word of POS verb.

Comment: BTW, what is your NLTK version?

Comment: When asking the question, it was the lastest I think.

Comment: This gives a synset-object. But how do we get a gloss (as was asked in the question) from that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by download this.
http://wordnet.princeton.edu/glosstag.shtml
Use the files in WordNet-3.0\glosstag\merged to create my own map dic.

Comment: Apperently, the link does not exist anymore. I guess the new location is https://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/glosstag.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The first answer provides wrong answer. Also, there are many keys in wordnet
for which synset does not exists. For this reason, you can use the following code for wordnet 3.0:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def synset_from_key(sense_key):
    lem=wn.lemma_from_key(sense_key)
    return lem.synset()

key='england%1:15:00::'
try:
    ss=synset_from_key(ky)
    print(ss)
except:
    print("No Synset Found.")
```

You can also find the definition by using:
`print(ss.definition())` 
More details can be found at: https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).